# Observation of Strange Pattern with He-Ne Laser passing through a sample of Chlorophyll

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser, non-linear-optics

We Designed in our lab an experiment with 5mW He-Ne laser, passing through Chlorophyll, which was extracted from Hibiscus rosa-sinensis leaves dipped in Ethanol. The resultant pattern we observed on the screen was[image]

We were expecting Chlorophyll to absorb in the wavelength of He-Ne laser, and thereby exhibiting nonlinear optical effects of self-focussing and defocussing.

*"Self-focusing and self-trapping in new types of Kerr media with large nonlinearities" Zhang et.al*
https://doi.org/10.1364/OL.14.000695

We used a cylindrical glass tube for placing the sample, instead of a cuvette. So it could have acted as a cylindrical lens, as can be seen from the way the tube has focussed the beam along a line instead of a point as seen in spherical lens.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_lens

But the pattern disappeared when chlorophyll was poured out
[image]

1. The sample still had ethanol in it, during the expt as it was kept covered.
2. The sample was just poured out in the second fig, the tube was not cleaned.
3. The images are from a smartphone camera.

   I would like to know what possibly could have caused this image pattern.

Comment: Please clarify: in the second figure, is the tube empty, or does it have liquid in it?

Comment: The sample was poured out, but the tube was not washed, so there are some droplets of the sample sticking to the walls.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend an experiment: fill the tube with ethanol and send the laser beam through again to see what happens.  The tube when filled with liquid will certainly act as a cylindrical lens.  I have not found data on the refractive index vs wavelength for chlorophyll, but because there is an absorption peak in the red range, the refractive index may behave a bit strangely there.  You might also experiment with different concentrations of chlorophyll in the ethanol and see if the pattern depends on the concentration.  If it does, then you can use, e.g. sugar water in various concentrations (that is, different refractive indices) to try to duplicate the pattern.

Finally, optical nonlinearities are intensity-dependent.  You can eliminate the possibility of the pattern being due to optical nonlinearities by reducing the beam intensity to a very low level and seeing if the pattern is the same.  If it is the same at very low beam intensity, then you can safely conclude that you are not observing anything due to optical nonlinearity.

Answer (score 0):

to know if the change in pattern is due to Chlorophyl then the 2 setups should only change by chlorophyl amount and nothing else

1- the paper to test tube distance should be the same to compare patterns

2- As @S.McGrew noted, you need the test tube filled with ethanol in the 2nd case too.